BertWordPieceTokenizer ignores multiple-Chinese-character vocabularies during encoding in vocab.txt
I use BertWordPieceTokenizer (source), trying to train the tokenizer with a predefined vocabulary list, which the list contains 1 - 5 Chinese characters per line and the first 1000 lines are special characters like [PAD] and [CLS].
Here is the code I used:
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer
# https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/blob/main/bindings/python/py_src/tokenizers/implementations/bert_wordpiece.py

bert_tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer(
    "data/bertwordpiece_vocab.txt",
    clean_text=True,
    handle_chinese_chars=True,
    strip_accents=True,
    lowercase=True,
)

bert_tokenizer.train(
    "data/large_text_file_for_training.txt",
    vocab_size = 100000,
    min_frequency = 100
)

print(bert_tokenizer)

The output is:
Tokenizer(vocabulary_size=3342, model=BertWordPiece, unk_token=[UNK], sep_token=[SEP], cls_token=[CLS], pad_token=[PAD], mask_token=[MASK], clean_text=True, handle_chinese_chars=True, strip_accents=True, lowercase=True, wordpieces_prefix=##)

Looks normal to me.
Last, to test the ability of the tokenizer, I use the .encode() function:
bert_tokenizer.encode("我哋今日去睇陳奕迅演唱會").tokens

The output is:
['[CLS]',
 '我',
 '哋',
 '今',
 '日',
 '去',
 '睇',
 '陳',
 '[UNK]',
 '[UNK]',
 '演',
 '唱',
 '會',
 '[SEP]']

but the expected result is:
['[CLS]',
 '我哋',
 '今日',
 '去',
 '睇',
 '陳奕迅',
 '演唱會',
 '[SEP]']

which the tokens of each expected result are included in the original vocab.txt. The training process simply just ignores the vocabularies and gives unknown tokens [UNK] in the encode() result.
How can I obtain the expected result?
